# Getting undefined after value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var input = $(document.createElement('input')); 
input.attr("type", "file");
input.attr("id", "files");
input.attr("name", "files[]");
input.trigger('click');
alert(input.attr("value"));
```

The above script open the file browser window and i am able to select the file as well, but in alert am seeing undefined, how to get actual file name  in the alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this:

```
var input = $("<input />");
```

And also bind the alert with the `change` event.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  var input = $("<input />"); 
  input.attr("type", "file");
  input.attr("id", "files");
  input.attr("name", "files[]");
  input.trigger('click');
  $("body").append(input);
  input.change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to get full path of the file, instead just filename

Comment: @Bharanikumar Macha it is a safety precaution of the browsers da... If you use Chrome, it says, `C:\fakepath\filename`. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

> One needs to use `change` listener to get the value from the `input type='file'`. In your example there is not attribute `value` in your element hence it is returning `undefined`.
>
> You have the freedom to use `$("<input />")` or `$(document.createElement('input'));` but if you are doing it jQuery way then go for the former.

Try this:

```js
var input = $("<input />");
input.attr("type", "file");
input.attr("id", "files");
input.attr("name", "files[]");
$('body').append(input);
input.on('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you could either use

```js
   
var input = document.createElement('input');
```

or

```js
var input = $("<input />");
```

you are having code wrong by syntax

please refer the how you can add element

[Refer Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)